# Краш при инициализации переменной

Tags: android, java

Доброго дня, пытаюсь создать переменную следующим образом:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     File myF = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename");
   ...........
```

но при запуске происходит краш. Знаю точно что проблема именно в этой строке, ибо без неё все работает как часы.
Привожу LogCat:

```
  07-05 07:08:07.774: I/dalvikvm(622): Debugger is active
  07-05 07:08:07.964: I/System.out(622): Debugger has connected
  07-05 07:08:07.964: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:08.164: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:08.375: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:08.575: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:08.774: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:08.975: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:09.184: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:09.386: I/System.out(622): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-05 07:08:09.588: I/System.out(622): debugger has settled (1367)
  07-05 07:08:10.098: D/dalvikvm(622): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
  07-05 07:09:17.504: D/AndroidRuntime(622): Shutting down VM
  07-05 07:09:17.504: W/dalvikvm(622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kgcontrol/com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:185)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:68)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
  07-05 07:09:19.394: E/AndroidRuntime(622):    ... 11 more
```

прошу помочь, не первый день бьюсь на этим, а знаний не хватает т.к. новичок ещё

Comment: А что возвращает `getFilesDir()`? `null` небось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенесите инициализацию `myF` в `onCreate()`.

Comment: не пойдёт, эта переменная нужна мне как глобальная, ибо в других функциях используется, как выкрутиться в этом случае?

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, ну так оставьте объявление `myF` как поля класса, но перенесите его инициализацию в `onCreate()`.